# TS 2740 Type 'ShadowRoot' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 63 more

Tags: typescript, svelte

Getting this error. See code below. I'm new to both TypeScript and Svelte.

```
const root = document.querySelector('overlay')?.shadowRoot
const app = new App({
    target: root,
})
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is giving the error because it is an error. Svelte doesn't yet support this, but hopefully will soon [Reference](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/5870)